# How to use regex to extract a substring, manipulate the substring and re-insert it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Odata query string (I've split the string over 3 lines for easier reading but in  reality is a single line)

```
/odata/businessreport?%24top=25&%24skip=0&%24count=true&%24format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata.metadata%3Dfull&%24filter=()%20and%20
PurchaseDate%20nIN%202023-11-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%20and%20
ForeignBarcode%20eq%20'abcd1234'
```

In Javascript, I need to manipulate the purchase-date parameter like so, from

```
PurchaseDate%20nIN%202023-11-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z
```

to

```
date(PurchaseDate)%20eq%202023-11-20
```

(that is: add the date function with brackets, change nIN to eq and strip the time)

**Question: Is there a regex one liner to do this?**

Here is my attempt

```
//define the input

let input =
"/odata/businessreport?%24top=25&%24skip=0&%24count=true&%24format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata.metadata%3Dfull&%24filter=()%20and%20PurchaseDate%20nIN%202023-02-02T23%3A00%3A00.000Z%20and%20ForeignBarcode%20eq%20'abcd1234"


//extract the date (using look behind and look ahead)
let rdate = /(?<=PurchaseDate%20nIN%20)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=T\d{2}%3A\d{2}%3A\d{2}.\d{3}Z)/
let date = rdate.exec(input)

//use regex and some string manipulation to replace the orignal substring
input.replace(/PurchaseDate%20nIN%20\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}%3A\d{2}%3A\d{2}.\d{3}Z/,`date(PurchaseDate%20eq%20${date[0]})`)

//result
// /odata/businessreport?%24top=25&%24skip=0&%24count=true&%24format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata.metadata%3Dfull&%24filter=()%20and%20date(PurchaseDate)%20eq%202023-02-02)%20and%20ForeignBarcode%20eq%20'abcd1234
```

Comment: are you submitting this request as a client to an api or processing this request as the server?

Comment: submitting as a client to an api, why?

Comment: in that case, you can parse the input to the `fetch()` prior to sending the request with `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams`.

Comment: [`input.replace(/%20([^%]+)%20nIN%20(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.+Z/, '%20date($1)%20eq%20$2');`](https://regex101.com/r/rWZ9J8/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid regex for encoded strings. Consider parsing the URL first, then replacing what you need to. You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class to parse it first.

```js
let path = "/odata/businessreport?%24top=25&%24skip=0&%24count=true&%24format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata.metadata%3Dfull&%24filter=()%20and%20PurchaseDate%20nIN%202023-11-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%20and%20ForeignBarcode%20eq%20'abcd1234'";
let url = new URL(path, "http://example.com");
let filter = url.searchParams.get("$filter");
filter = filter.replace(/PurchaseDate nIN (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.*?Z/, "date(PurchaseDate) = $1");
url.searchParams.set("$filter", filter);
console.log(filter);
console.log(url.pathname + url.search);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try the following regex replacement with the help of capture groups:

```js
var input = "PurchaseDate%20nIN%202023-11-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z";
var output = input.replace(/PurchaseDate%(\d+).*?%(\d{6})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T.*?\.\d{3}[A-Z]/, "date(PurchaseDate)%$1eq%$2-$3-$4");
console.log(output);
```